# Any QuickBlocks tutorial?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, external-api, explorer-api, exchange-api

From my understanding QuickBlocks is an api in C++ that provides similar services as etherscan API for the ethereum blockchain. Is there a link or tutorial to use [quickkblocks](https://quickblocks.io/) because the example in the documentation is kind of hard to understand.

It seems like the name was changed to true blocks since the github repo is [this](https://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/trueblocks-core).  I am looking for a comprehensive one and c++ beginner friendly.

Comment: (Thomas is the developer/owner of QuickBlocks, and will like see this question and be best placed to answer. There's a 2-part tutorial [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/exploring-the-ethereum-blockchain-with-quickblocks-part-1-f32985d8e5ab) and one [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-time-ordered-index-of-time-ordered-immutable-data-e28ced3417cc).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question. We did change the name of the project from QuickBlocks to TrueBlocks. Link is here: http://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/trueblocks-core.

I'll admit that the documentation is quite poor. There is currently no good tutorials. If you're interested in writing one, perhaps there's a bounty in it for you. There is a little bit of sample code here: https://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/trueblocks-core/tree/master/src/examples.

Please join our discord to discuss: https://discord.gg/nWfBXa

(Sorry Gods of this Stack Exchange. I didn't know how else to answer this. Once we get a tutorial in place, I'll edit this to include a directl link.)